# how can i order recyclerview items in firebase by replay timestamps

Tags: android

how can I order my recyclerview items like this

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
productQuery = mDatabaseReference.child("Blog").orderByChild("replaydate");
```

"replaydate" is located in Replay>psotkey>replaydate I want order blog items by repaydate, is this possiple?

[image: this image show my database]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the messages by timestamp order you can use

```
 database.orderByChild("replydate").limitToLast(10)
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
    Model newModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);  
//Model is you model which you are using for showing data in recyclerview
    arraylist.add(newModel);
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I want the child of Blog ordered by replaydate..take a loke to my image to see the root of Blog and replaydate..is this possible?